# Validity of a specific argument

Tags: logic

Assume that $a\Rightarrow\neg b$ and $\neg b \Rightarrow \gamma$. Does it *follow* that $a\Rightarrow \gamma$ ? A book on logic I have been studying claims that the above is **not** a valid argument; however, I cannot find a case where the premises are true and the conclusion false.

Comment: It is valid; see [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic).

Comment: Please name and shame the book.